# Creating custom header variable using Fiddler proxy server

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I understand that Fiddler proxy server supports custom HTTP header variables.  I'm new at this, my goal is to simulate a passed custom variable the way an F5 appliance would pass an HTTP header variable (string) for a web app. The variable string is used to authenticate the user.  I do not have access to a load balancing appliance and have to find a way to simualte or manually add it.

Will apreciate any input on how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 6):

You can add your own header variables to the OnBeforeRequest function (or OnBeforeResponse) within CustomRules.js, such as the following:

oSession.oRequest["NewHeaderName"] = "New header value";

More info:  http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse

Comment: This is the best approach, but for simpler tasks, simply click the **Filters** tab and use the appropriate box to set a Request header and value.